# What does " 自分の胸に聞いて頂戴 " mean? Not Literally

Tags: translation, words, meaning

Not the literal meaning, I know its some sort of tsukkomi, but I can't quite figure out what it means.

The best idea I've got is something along the lines of "give me back my concern" or something like that. I'm probably way off though.

Comment: The literal meaning would be "Ask yourself" or "Ask your own conscience" as you might already know, but if you need a contextual translation I think you should give us some context.

Comment: http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E8%83%B8%E3%81%AB%E8%81%9E%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most often means:

**"You (should) know the answer deep down."**